# Change float to desired format in an NSPredicate filter part

Tags: formatting, floating-point, nspredicate

Here's what I got:

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pressure=%f",
                                                 [self.txtInput.text floatValue]];
```

Is there a way I can format the "pressure" property so that it matches the float value of whatever is input to a text box? For instance, there's an object with a pressure value of 2504.6 and I input 2504.6 to the text box. But as I convert the text to float it turns to 2504.600098. As 2504.6 does not equal 2504.600098 I don't get right result from filtering.Precisions of the properties differ,so I cannot compare them to a certain format.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a single digit of precision you can use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pressure=%.1f",
                                             [self.txtInput.text floatValue]];
```

it follows the standard `printf` formatting rules, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf) is a table with more details.

Comment: The thing is I've got a value-2504.6. This is the value of the property that is used in the predicate. I need some way to increase the precision from one to six. With the way you suggested I will just get the float value of the text precision down to 1. I need to determine the precision of the property in the predicate, not the compared value.